# Using Chrome Custom Tabs for a login window, can I disable the "Open in Browser" menu option?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

In our Android app, we're using a [Chrome Custom tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/) to implement an OAuth-based login flow, as outlined in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdQTXrk6YTk

One issue I'm having is the Custom Tab menu: in the top-right section includes a way to "break out" of the Custom Tab and launch the login page in the "full" Chrome application:

[image]

**Is there a way to disable this "Open in Chrome" menu item, or hide the entire menu?** The only API I've found is to add menu items, not remove them: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.Builder#addmenuitem